# Retriving data from MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have written a method in java which retrieves data from MySQL database and adds into a list. But the method returns null values for few of the IDs although there are data in database.

Here is the code:

```
public static List getPostTime(int ID) {

  List<Timestamp> time = new ArrayList();

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        Connection con;

        con = DBConnection.getDBConnection();
        String queryTime = "select created from tbl_posts_98 where `MakerID` = \'" + ID + "\'";

        ps = con.prepareStatement(queryTime);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            time.add(rs.getTimestamp(1));
        }

    } catch (java.lang.Throwable t) {
        //System.out.println(t.getClass().getName()); //this'll tell you what class has been thrown
        t.printStackTrace(); //get a stack trace
    }
    return time;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We don't need to see your java code as this is a sql/data issue. We need to see your db structure and data to be be able to help you with this.

Comment: When you say data is null, do you mean rs is null ?

Comment: I would suggest using a debugger to break after your query string is built, copy the actual value of the query string and run it in MySQL to see if you are actually getting results back.  Also, its bad coding practice to build a query string through concatenation.  There are methods that allow you to do variable substitution in your query string that handles escaping your values appropriately to avoid things like SQL injection.

Comment: tbl_posts_98 is a table having almost all of the fields in varchar. The column which I am trying to retrieve, has following types of data '2008-01-10T19:00:09Z' and this field is also varchar field.

Comment: @VKSingla: Yes the rs is null.

Comment: @CodeChimp: Yes I have checked the query string into MySQL, I can see data there. And thank you for the suggestion, I will avoid query string through concatenation.

Comment: I think there may be error in building query like there may be some space in those IDs, Try to trim the ID before passing into the query.

Comment: @VKSingla: I have printed the query string, there are not any space in IDs.

Comment: Basically there is some error in the query. and if it is not working for few IDs it means the ID is not matching with what that is in DB. Try to check in DB if there is any space preceding or succeeding the ID.

Comment: I have printed the query in java and I have taken the same printed query from java and ran in MySQL. The query returns the result in MySQL. But I get null in java from the same query. I have also checked in DB, there are not any space preceding or succeeding the IDs. Thank You for the time.

Comment: Turn on query logging in MySQL and watch what is actually being passed to the db in case this differs from what you are printing

Comment: So, your key is a varchar that holds a date formatted string?  If so, I would check for issues with casing and make sure none of the characters in the incoming string has any special chars, like '.  I agree with others...if you are getting no results, it's because your IDs are not matching 100%.

Comment: The problem is because of multiple connection with database. Now, I am closing the connection with database after the work is done. This has solved my above problem. Thank You everyone for you time.